# remove the height after using transform

Tags: html, css, transform

Let I use transform in this:

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}


.first {
  height: 100px;
}
    
.second {
  height: 100px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

So, after using transform: translateY(-50%); the height of parent element should reduce as it is not using full space. But the height of parent div is still 200px.

How can we remove extra space and I want to use transform only?

https://jsfiddle.net/r4c3g02o/12/

Comment: use negative margin instead to get this effect

Comment: negative margin still apply

Comment: @TemaniAfif But I want to use transform only.

Comment: you cannot ....

Answer (score 1):

`translate` only *visually* moves an element. It does not effect the flow of other elements in the document.

Perhaps the simplest way to achieve your desired result would be a negative margin.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

.first {
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.second {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">
    First
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    second
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to use transform only

Comment: Your update makes no difference: https://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/d3jqfru1/7/

Comment: You can not achieve what you describe using transform.

Answer (score -1):

I think y can use SVG and `<animateTransform>` so)

Comment: Use for which div?

Comment: `.second `, if y want to remove height for this one

Comment: try this. maybe if y r making an animation SVG will do it better